# Crafter CMS 3.0 No Site is Set

Tags: crafter-cms

I'm new to Crafter CMS.
After download and start Crafter CMS as construction guide at http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/getting-started/quick-start-guide.html#installing-crafter-cms-from-the-zip-download.
I open site localhost:9080/studio, but instead of showing login page as description, it only show this screen:
[click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OQ1h.jpg)

Please help me solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Studio (that helps you build sites), you need to go to: http://localhost:8080/studio

Port 9080 goes to the delivery engine.

For more information on the architecture, you should checkout: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/architecture.html

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thank you very much.